# Dynamic SelectField options based on a second SelectField with Flask_wtf

Tags: python, flask, dynamic, flask-wtforms

**Overview**
I am building an online omics database with a BLAST function, and I want users to be able to BLAST either annotations (cds/protein) or the assemblies, all in one page. I'm using a Flask framework with WTForms via Flask_wtf.

To do so, I want to have two fields users can select: a target (either assemblies or annotations) and algorithm (BLASTn/tBLASTn for assemblies, BLASTn/p/x/tBLASTn for annotations).I'd like it to automatically update the algorithm form depending on what the user currently has selected in the Target field.

I can get the BLAST to work on both annotations and assemblies using static options, but if I try dynamic options for the algorithm SelectField, nothing shows up at all.

**This is what I've tried:**
I'm using the application factory model. The BLAST page and functions are all on a blueprint file. The form is on a separate forms.py file.

This is the form I have set up:

```py
class BlastForm(FlaskForm):
    seq = TextAreaField('Input nucleotide or protein sequence:', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=10)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Paste sequence here"})
    threshold = DecimalField('E-value threshold:', validators=[InputRequired(), NumberRange(min=1e-101, max=10)], default=0.01)                                           
    algorithm = SelectField('Algorithm', coerce=str, validators=[InputRequired()])
    target = SelectField('Select to BLAST against annotations or assemblies', choices=[('annotations', "Annotations"),('assemblies', "Assemblies")], default='annotations')
```

On the blueprint, I have these functions:

```py
@blastview.route('/update_algorithms', methods=['POST'])
def update_algorithms():
    target = request.form['target']
    algorithm = get_blast_algorithm(target)
    #print(f"Algorithm options for {target}: {algorithm}")
    return jsonify(options=algorithm)


def get_blast_algorithm(target):
    if target == 'annotations':
        return [('blastp', 'BLASTp'), ('blastn', 'BLASTn'), ('blastx', 'BLASTx'), ('tblastn', 'tBLASTn')]
    elif target == 'assemblies':
        return [('blastn', 'BLASTn'), ('tblastn', 'tBLASTn')]
    else:
        return []




@blastview.route('blast', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def blast():
    blastform = BlastForm()
    q = Queue('blast', connection=Redis())
    if blastform.validate_on_submit():
        annotationtable = AnnotationTable()
        seq = request.form['seq']
        target = request.form['target']
        query = annotationtable.query.get(seq)
        threshold = request.form['threshold']
        algorithm = request.form['algorithm']
        #algorithm = get_blast_algorithm(target)
        jobid = str(uuid.uuid4())
        if query is not None:
            if algorithm in ['blastp', 'blastx']:
                seq = query.Proteinseq
            elif algorithm in ['blastn', 'tblastn']:
                seq = query.Nucleotideseq
            else:
                #Just in case it really tries to get through and load something that doesn't exist
                seq = seq
            job = q.enqueue(do_blast, seq, algorithm, threshold, jobid, target, job_id=jobid, result_ttl=604800, job_timeout=600)
            current_app.logger.info(f"Logtype='Info'; Page='/blast/; Message='BLAST job quered using gene name, Args: jobID: {jobid}, algorithm: {algorithm}, threshold: {threshold}'")
            return redirect('/blast/' + job.id)
        else:
            job = q.enqueue(do_blast, seq, algorithm, threshold, jobid, target, job_id=jobid, result_ttl=604800, job_timeout=600) #Redis and Flask-RQ2 method #604800 is seconds in a week
            #job = do_blast.queue(seq, algorithm, queue="default") #Flask-RQ2 only method
            #job = do_blasttest.queue(seq, algorithm, queue="blast", timeout=60) #Test method, Flask-RQ2 only
            #job = q.enqueue(do_blasttest, seq, algorithm) #Test method, Redis and Flask-RQ2 method
            #current_app.logger.info("BLAST job queued")
            #current_app.logger.info(f"Logtype='Info'; Page='/blast/; Message='BLAST job quered, Args: jobID: {jobid}, algorithm: {algorithm}, threshold: {threshold}'")
            current_app.logger.info(f"Logtype='Info'; Page='/blast/; Message='BLAST job quered, Args: jobID: {jobid}, algorithm: {algorithm}, threshold: {threshold}'")
            return redirect('/blast/' + job.id)
    else:
        #blastform.seq.default = 'Default text'
        #blastform.process()
        return render_template('blast.html', blastform=blastform)
```

And on the BLAST template I have this form:

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="d-grid d-flex justify-content-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="insertExampleFasta()">Insert Example FASTA</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                {{ blastform.csrf_token }}
                {{ blastform.seq.label(class_="form-label") }}
                {{ blastform.seq(rows=10, class_="form-control", id="sequence-textarea") }} 
                
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="row my-3">
                <div class="col col-md-4 my-3">
                    {{ blastform.threshold.label(class_="form-label") }}
                    {{ blastform.threshold(class_="form-control") }}
                </div>
                <div class="col col-md-4 my-3">
                    {{ blastform.target.label(class_="form-label") }}
                    {{ blastform.target(class_="form-control") }}
                </div>
                <div class="col col-md-4 my-3">
                    {{ blastform.algorithm.label(class_="form-label") }}
                    {{ blastform.algorithm(class_="form-control") }}
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit BLAST Search</button>
        </form>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
    // Update algorithm choices based on the selected target
    $('#target').change(function () {
        var selectedTarget = $(this).val();
        
        $.ajax({
            url: '/update_algorithms',
            data: { target: selectedTarget },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                // Log the response for debugging
                console.log(response);

                // Update algorithm choices
                $('#algorithm').empty();
                $.each(response.options, function (value, text) {
                    $('#algorithm').append($('<option>').val(value).text(text));
                });
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});

    </script>
```

Are there any issues with this code I am using? The JavaScript near the end doesn't seem to actually be doing anything. I tried changing the JavaScript to have its own static option for testing, but that didn't do anything either. I do have JQuery installed.

Comment: did you check if you have errors in `JavaScript Console` in `DevTools` in `Firefox` or `Chrome`? You may also use `console.log(...)` to send information to `JavaScript Console` - and you can see what code is executed. You could use it to check if you have `'id="algorithm"` in HTML. maybe it has `name="algorithm"`